# How To Find Out If A Listelement Is Invalid

Tags: performance, list, swap

I got two lists with tuples of the form **(studentID, examID, points)**, examList and practiceList

The **studentID** is a seven digit positive number.

The examID is generated like this: **examID = randomInteger - studentID**.

We can assume that the **exameID is always: 9.999.999 >= examID >= 10.000.000**

For each examID I pick a randomInteger which I haven't used before. And I only use the randomInteger if the result for the examID is a seven digit number too (like the studentID).

Imagine there are some invalid entries inside the examList. The invalid entries would be of the following form: **(examID, studentID, points)**, so examID and studentID are swapped.

So if I wanted to use those two lists, for example to calculate the total amount of points for each student, I first need to find out which of the entries is invalid.
So **how can I find out if an entry is valid or invalid?** (preferable in a performant way)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is just too obvious.

The examID is generated like this:  **examID = randomInteger - studentID**
And we know that **the randomInteger is unique for each student**.

So if we change the equation like this: **randomInteger = examID + studentID**, we only get **unique** integer values.

We can **use** this equation **as hash function** to **generate a hash table**. So we make sure that every student gets his own index in the hash table.

By doing it this way we can assure **a linear running time of O(n)**.
It's also possible to construct the algorithm in a way that we only need to **execute the hash function 2*n times**. (n is the amount of students)